# Why is my profile picture suddenly inconsistent between the navigation bar and elsewhere?

Tags: support, bug, profile-picture

Sometime in the last hour or so, the profile picture shown in my navigation bar changed, and is no longer consistent with my profile picture elsewhere:

[image]

I haven't changed my profile today (or anytime recently). It happens across SE sites. If it's relevant, my profile pic is a Gravatar.

Bug?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, a bug.

On the Gravatar side.

We've been getting reports of this kind of issue more frequently recently, but not much we can do as the bug is on the Gravatar end.

People have found that uploading your image again to Gravatar can sometimes solve the issue.

Alternatively, upload the image to Stack Exchange and change over to that from Gravatar.

Comment: Huh, that didn't occur to me, as it's consistently correct in some places and consistently incorrect in others. Looking more closely, I can see that the pic in the navigation bar is `s=48` (48px), but the small pics elsewhere are `s=32` or `s=64`. So it's having trouble with the 48px size. Suddenly, out of nowhere.

Comment: *but not much we can do as the bug is on the Gravatar end* > Are there any alternatives for Gravatar SO would consider using? The bugs seem to get a lot worse the last time.

Comment: @PatrickHofman - we are looking at alternatives, but... not that simple and if we were to offer such a service instead - not trivial to implement.