# Icon bug for some badge's winner

Tags: bug, badges

I wanted to report a small possible cache bug.

On some users in the Windows where you can see who get awarded a badge, in the "Help Center > Badges > Tags", it seem to have a cache issue for the icon displayed for some users.

An example there over the user Brian Campbell; https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/80?page=2

[image]

You can see another example there https://serverfault.com/help/badges/256/sheriff over the user voretaq7 and splattne;

[image]

Thanks !

Comment: This issue is not isolated to the badge page, and is in fact an issue with Gravatar. For example, one related post: http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/291474 (There are a few others, this has come up a few times lately.)

Comment: Does a hard refresh of the page solve this?

Comment: @Oded No, I tried another browser too, to be sure, but for the same result

Comment: Gravatar have been having more and more problems like this recently - it is a bug on their end.